# comprehension question: modulo representation of polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a Unique factorization domain, $p \in R$ be a prime element and $f \in R[x]$. Consider $f + pR[x]$.

Let $f := 4x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x - 2 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

- If $p = 3$, then $f + pR[x] = x^3+1$, but why does this apply? I would have expected $x^3 - 2$. Why is $-2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$? How do I calculate the coefficients mod 3?
- If p = 5, then $f + pR[x] = -x^3 -2x^2-2x-2$, but why does this apply? I would have expected no change, as the absolute value of all coefficients is $\in [0,5)$.

Comment: In both the questions, it should be $f+pR[x]$ instead of $pR[x].$ Also $-2 \equiv 1 (mod 3)$ because $3|(-2-1).$ Similarly for the other cases. In the second question, may be the author(s) need it in this particular form. You can leave it as it is, or you can change it according to your need. Both are same.

Comment: @Krish thank you, I corrected the question. Would it still be correct, if I would leave the $-2$ in the term, or do I have to replace it with $1$ in order to be correct?

Comment: @muffel I added an answer that explains the idea behind these reductions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing : $-2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ because $-2-1=-3$ is divisible by $3$ (I suppose here that $R=\mathbb{Z}$ as the example suggests it). Then, if you want to calculate $f$ mod $3R[x]$ then you do :

$$f=(x^4+1)+(3x^3+3x^2+3x-3)=(x^4+1)+3(x^3+x^2+x-1) $$

The first polynomial is a representative of $f$ mod $3R[x]$ because the second is in $3R[x]$. Actually $f$ would also be a good representative of $f$ mod $3R[x]$ but it has more coefficients and the mod $3$ operation allows you to go to simpler polynomials. The same thing applies to your second example :

$$f=(-x^3-2x^2-2x-2)+5(x^3+x^2+x) $$

You could also say that :

$$f=(4x^3+3x^2+3x+3)+5\times 1 $$

Then you get different representatives of the same class mod $5$.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the author is employing a balanced complete set of reps for the integers mod $n,\,$ i.e. reps of least magnitude, e.g. for $\, p = 5\,$ this means to use the reps (remainders) $\, 0,\pm1, \pm2\,$ vs. $\,0,1,2,3,4,5.\,$ So they reduce $\,3\equiv -2\,$ to its rep of least magnitude. This may be done because using least magnitude reps often simplifies calculations (esp. hand calculations), for example $\,{\rm mod}\ n\!:\ (n\!-\!1)^{2k}\equiv (-1)^{2k}\equiv 1\,$ by reducing $\,n\!-\!1\equiv -1\,$ to its least maginitude rep.